# Visual Basic Decimal Type

Tags: vb.net, types, decimal, basic

So this question  I am working on ask you to code a simple statement that was Base-16 followed by a newline character.
And use
Dim someValue As Integer = 346 to work with.
Would this be correct [see code]? I am not sure if I understand decimal in VB all that well... Because looks like this "0000000000000346".

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim someValue As Integer = 346
        Console.WriteLine("{0:D16}" + vbNewLine, someValue)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Sorry if my question is not clear.

Comment: Yes, your question is slightly unclear. Usually, the application is concerned with two things, **What is the input of the application?** and **What is the output of it?**. Anything in between may differ significantly. If your task is accomplishable using integer, then usage of integer is correct.

Comment: Are you trying to create a Base16 number from a Base10 number? Because that is what I understand from this. If that is the case then your result is wrong.

Comment: If you want to format your int in base 16 format you should use `Console.WriteLIne("{0:X2}" + vbNewLine, someValue)`

Comment: I am not sure my question is kinda unclear. It says "Code a statement that will display the following variable in base-16 followed by a newline character."
I am not sure if it means it wants hex. Which is the out put would be 1CA.

Comment: Base 16 is Hex - https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=346+in+hex

Comment: Base-16 **is** hex. There's no difference between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Convert.ToString() function has a [useful overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14kwkz77%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which will generate a string representation of a number in some different bases:

```
Dim someValue As Integer = 346
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(someValue, 16) & vbNewLine)
```